# How do I mock express.Application with Jest?

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, mocking, jestjs

Some class that takes express as an argument (basic DI):

```
class App {
  constructor(express: express.Application) { /* ... */ }
}
```

My test:

```
// this doesn't work ("argument not assignable"):
//const expressMock = jest.mock("express");
//let app = new App(expressMock);

// so how do I mock it?
const expressMock = ???
let app = new App(expressMock);
```

How do I mock `express.Application` with Jest? The whole thing, not just a request, or route, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Technically, `express.Application` cannot be mocked, it's an interface. It's an object that it represents that should be mocked.

As `jest.mock` [documentation](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestmockmodulename-factory-options)  states, it

> Returns the jest object for chaining.

So this is not a correct way to retrieve mocked object:

```
const expressMock = jest.mock("express");
```

A correct one would be

```
jest.mock("express");
...
const expressMock = require("express");
```

Moreover, `App` accepts not `express` factory function but application object, which is a result of `express()` call.

`jest.mock` without factory function results in auto-mocked `express` factory which won't produce proper application object.

Since `expressMock` is passed to `App` directly in tests, there's no necessity to mock Express module. A mock that contains bare minimum implementation can be passed instead:

```
const expressMock = {
  use: jest.fn(),
  ...
} as any as express.Application;

let app = new App(expressMock);
```

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful. You said "auto-mocked express factory which won't produce proper application object." - how do I produce a mocked application object?

Comment: With `const expressMock = {
  use: jest.fn(),
  ...
}`. If you need to mock a module, it's `jest.mock("express", () => () => expressMock)` then.

Comment: So in Jest I never get a full/deep mocked object, I need to create it myself with all its members like you did for `use`? (I'm new to this, I'm used to .NET mocking which seems to be quite different.)

Comment: `express.application` contains all methods that app instance contains. You can traverse over *original* `express.application` keys and create a mock object with these stubbed methods, they also need to return the obj because Express uses chaining. But the problem is that not every method chains.  E.g. `app.get('value')` is config getter and returns a value, while `app.get('path', ...)` is router and returns `app`. The mock inevitably becomes messy and potentially faulty.

Comment: There are auto-mocking libs in JS but they likely won't work for Express because it's old-school and doesn't use ES6 classes. Also they won't cover this thing with chaining. I'd generally advise against auto-mocking, especially with Express. It results in looser tests that are harder to debug when they fail. It's a good practice to test what exactly your unit does, at least in JS. If you use 5 methods from `app`, mock only them. If you change an app in a way that makes a test invalid like the use of 6th method, a test fails. And this is much better then a test that doesn't fail when it should.

Comment: Thank you for that deep insight my friend, I can tell it comes from years of experience. I'm new to Node/Jest testing, and some of these concepts are weird because I'm so used to .NET/Java testing which is VERY different in this case. I'll structure my tests the way you recommended, and forget about deep mocking, thanks!

Comment: Correct. With typed languages I can focus more on the "problem domain", but in JS/TS I must always be thinking about the "language domain" in addition to the problem domain.